# BGP Authentication Key-Chain Between Cisco IOS XE L3 Switch (c9300-24S) and Juniper MX480 Router

Tags: cisco, bgp, cisco-commands, authentication, juniper-mx

Need to create a BGP authentication keychain between Cisco and Juniper devices.  Need assistance with config commands for Cisco 9300-24S.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [IOS-XE documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bgp/configuration/xe-17/irg-xe-17-book/bgp-support-for-TCP-AO.html?dtid=osscdc000283) for configuring BGP MD5 authentication, it's pretty straight forward.  However, if there is something specific that isn't clear, please update your question.

Though do be aware that Juniper has a couple of options for authentication `authentication-key` and `authentication-key-chain`, they set different options in the TCP header and some are not compatible with other Cisco operating systems (i.e. IOS-XR)  [Here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16758/bgp-authentication-key-chain-vs-authentication-key) is an example I posted before outlining it.